# BroadcastReceiver and Retrofit make issue

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, retrofit

I'm using a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle the data from `FCM` in my activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    BroadcastReceiver mBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
            if(intent.getAction().equals("a")){
                function_a();
            }else if(intent.getAction().equals("b")){
                function_b();
            }
        }
   };

   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("a");
   filter.addAction("b");
   LocalBroadcastReceiver.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcast,filter);

   MyClient myClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(MyClient.class);
   Call<SampleItem> call = myClient.addSample(sampleData);

   call.enqueue(new Callback<SampleItem>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<SampleItem> call, Response<SampleItem> response){

           function_c();
       }
       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<SampleItem> call, Throwable t){

       }
   });
}
```

`Retrofit` send the data to the API and for response `function_c()` is performed. But after that the code runs `function_b()` and `function_a()`

Why `Retrofit`'s response effects on `BroadcastReceiver` functions?

Comment: Question is not clear enough .. You mean `onReceive()` is getting called automatically twice ?

Comment: @ADM yes, it called after onResponse()

Comment: Whats written inside `function_c()` add it with question .

Comment: @ADM it's not important at all. but if you want to know it just add an item to recyclerView.

Comment: Thats only means you have called `sendBroadcast` of `sendStickyBroadcast` somewhere .. Whats `LocalBroadcastReceiver` is it `LocalBroadcastManager`?

Comment: @ADM No, I didn't call `sendBroadcast` anywhere. and I tried to unregister `BroadcastReceiver` in `onResponse` and it worked and the code didn't run the other functions but the `BroadcastReceiver` didnt work no longer.